# "NetworkError: 404 Not Found" with a javascript file

Tags: javascript, firebug, http-status-code-404

I'm getting the following error from Firebug.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://myip/function%20()%20%7B%20%20%20%20tfObjSort.setThings(this);%20%20%20%20return%20this.sort(tfObjSort.charSorter);%7D/"
```

I assume that one of my javascripts caused it. The file is,

```
(function(){

 tfObjSort={
  init:function(){
    Array.prototype.objSort=function(){
      tfObjSort.setThings(this);
      var a=arguments;
      var x=tfObjSort;
      x.a=[];x.d=[];
      for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(typeof a[i]=="string"){x.a.push(a[i]);x.d.push(1)};
        if(a[i]===-1){x.d[x.d.length-1]=-1}
      }
      return this.sort(tfObjSort.sorter);
    };
    Array.prototype.strSort=function(){
      tfObjSort.setThings(this);
      return this.sort(tfObjSort.charSorter)
    }
  },
  sorter:function(x,y){
    var a=tfObjSort.a
    var d=tfObjSort.d
    var r=0
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
      if(typeof x+typeof y!="objectobject"){return typeof x=="object"?-1:1};
      var m=x[a[i]]; var n=y[a[i]];
      var t=typeof m+typeof n;
      if(t=="booleanboolean"){m*=-1;n*=-1}
      else if(t.split("string").join("").split("number").join("")!=""){continue};
      r=m-n;
      if(isNaN(r)){r=tfObjSort.charSorter(m,n)};
      if(r!=0){return r*d[i]}
    }
    return r;
  },
  charSorter:function(x,y){
    if(tfObjSort.ignoreCase){x=x.toLowerCase();y=y.toLowerCase()};
    var s=tfObjSort.chars;
    if(!s){return x>y?1:x<y?-1:0};
    x=x.split("");y=y.split("");l=x.length>y.length?y.length:x.length;
    var p=0;
    for(var i=0;i<l;i++){
      p=s.indexOf(x[i])-s.indexOf(y[i]);
      if(p!=0){break};
    };
    if(p==0){p=x.length-y.length};
    return p;
  },
  setThings:function(x){
    this.ignoreCase=x.sortIgnoreCase;
    var s=x.sortCharOrder;
    if(!s){this.chars=false;return true};
    if(!s.sort){s=s.split(",")};
    var a="";
    for(var i=1;i<1024;i++){a+=String.fromCharCode(i)};
    for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){
      z=s[i].split("");
      var m=z[0]; var n=z[1]; var o="";
      if(z[2]=="_"){o=n+m} else {o=m+n};
      a=a.split(m).join("").split(n).join(o);
    };
    this.chars=a;
  }
};

tfObjSort.init();  


}());
```

As far as I see, there's no problem with the script above.

What's the problem!?

Comment: You should describe what you're doing that causes this error to appear and explain what you've already tried to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like maybe you're writing out the function body itself into the hyperlink somewhere.  Does this happen when you click on a hyperlink?  Check to make sure you're using href="javascript:myFunction();" and binding your event handlers correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry, we don't have enough information to provide you with an answer.

Comment: //  I understand. I found what causes it. Wherever I put Array.prototype.something, it generates "NetworkError: 404 Not found" error..google returns nothing for such situation. Do you have any ideas?